# Payments installments in Cognito Forms

Tags: cognito-forms

I would like to know if it's possible to implement installment payments in the form.

For example, I use 3 payment choices:

- Credit card — $75
- Check — 1 installment $75
- Checks — 3 installments $25 x3

---

- First payment in June
- Second in July
- Third in August

Is this possible? And if yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

Cognito Forms does not currently support installment payments.

We have two features on our public Idea Board specifically related to supporting installment/scheduled payments. While we have researched adding support for this, we do not currently have a specific timeframe in mind for releasing this capability.

https://trello.com/c/iClvWf6Q/226-partial-payment

https://trello.com/c/1XpfGKm8/134-subscription-billing-recurring-payments